# How to find all occurances after one word found

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new on regex, I wonder if can I insert one line based of the occurrence of a line before.

If a line `teste = ""` exists, I want to add `@@@` after the next `</cfscript>`.

**Input:**

```
<cfscript>
    this.someThing(
    ...
    teste = "" 

    );
</cfscript>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<cfscript>
    this.someThing(
    ...
    teste = "" 

    );
</cfscript>
 @@@
```

Comment: im using coldfusion but... im trying to do that as VScode, i have bunch of projects openned and im trying to run a full change in all files

Comment: I want to find all lines with teste = "" and place @@@ after the first </cfscript> of that occurency

Comment: Do you mean `(teste = ""[\s\S]*?<\/cfscript>)`? Replace it with `\1\n@@@`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/4SG2pH/1

Comment: That might workout for me man, tks

Comment: If it didn't try `(teste = ""[\s\S\r\n]*?</cfscript>)` and replace with `$1\n@@@`. VSCode is tricky to deal with.

Comment: Your regex worked, so i upvoted it, but the end of everything this will not workout for me... since VScode not allow me to run directly regex, i will only be able to use regex to change things, i would love be able to search and change, but thanks anyways

Comment: VSC allows you to work with regexes. You only have to enable it on ctrl + f pane.

Comment: Wow i was trying to use on Seach bar, in ctrl + f really worked, thanks